# How should I handle the automatic duplicate answer flags?

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, duplicate-answers

I find the "*duplicate answers (auto)*" flag the most difficult to handle on Stack Overflow. Here's how I try to handle the situation, but I'd appreciate some further pointers and corrections if this is not correct:

- First, I check if the questions are duplicates. Exact duplicate answers typically mean duplicate questions and if this is the case, I vote to close accordingly.
- I post a comment under the most recent answer, explaining that duplicate answers should not be posted and that the user should flag/vote-to-close as a duplicate.
- If I feel able to do so, I judge the answer like any answer and vote accordingly.
- I then mark the flag as invalid to make it go away.

Is there any further action I should be taking other than the above? Is it OK to mark the flag as invalid in this way - seems a little awkward?

Comment: (The related sidebar is magic and makes my searching ability seem rather poor...)

Comment: You just commented that your dupe question about dupe answers is a dupe in itself?!

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Yup! Nothing came up in my searching, but as usual the "Related" sidebar put me to shame almost immediately after I posted. But I prefer not to delete my questions if they are duplicates as they just increase the search terms that may lead to the other question.